# Add MS Office communicator presence indicator into JSP

Tags: java, user-presence, office-communicator

I want to add MS Office communicator presence indicator into my Java Application(jsp).

Comment: If you're happy with the answer below, could you mark it as Accepted, to help anyone else browsing these questions? Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

If you're targeting the windows platform, the simplest way is to do everything client-side.
As long as the clients are running IE, Office 2003 or above, and Communicator 2007 or above, you can use the [NameCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455335.aspx) ActiveX object that gets distributed with Office.

The following code should get you started:

```
<script>

var sipUri = "your.contact@your.domain.com";

var nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject('Name.NameCtrl.1');
if (nameCtrl.PresenceEnabled)
{
  nameCtrl.OnStatusChange = onStatusChange;
  nameCtrl.GetStatus(sipUri, "1");
}


function onStatusChange(name, status, id)
{
  // This function is fired when the contacts presence status changes.
  // In a real world solution, you would want to update an image to reflect the users presence
  alert(name + ", " + status + ", " + id);
}

function ShowOOUI()
{
  nameCtrl.ShowOOUI(sipUri, 0, 15, 15);
}

function HideOOUI()
{
  nameCtrl.HideOOUI();
}

</script>

<span onmouseover="ShowOOUI()" onmouseout="HideOOUI()" style="border-style:solid">Your Contact</span>
```

For a real world solution, you'd just need to implement an image that changes depending on the presence state that gets returned (i.e. a presence bubble to display alongside each users name), and a collection of sip uris to images, to ensure you can map an incoming status change to the relevant image.