# Making audio calls using Microsoft Lync from a third party application - Lync SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat, lync-2010, lync

We have a chat application which works on ASP.Net web applications. We want to allow users to make calls to other users through our chat application. To provide that we want to make use of Microsoft Lync 2010 and use their SDK to leverage its capabilities and make calls. Any pointers on how to do that will be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options here - you could use the [NameCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455335.aspx) control to integrate presence and a pop-up menu into your aspx pages - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130904/add-ms-office-communicator-presence-indicator-into-jsp) for more details, and an example.

Assuming you're not using Silverlight, you could create a .NET assembly that uses the SDK to initiate a call (see [the walkthrough here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436797.aspx)), and then expose this to COM using .NET's COM Interop features - example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923350/building-com-interop-library-for-asp-classic-using-4-0-framework-vs2010/4934033#4934033), if you haven't done this before

Also, Sevki's answer is a great way to get up and running quickly, although you won't be able to get the presence of the user that way.

All of this assumes that the users have Lync running on their machine, i.e. assumes you won't be opening chat up to users outside your organisation who may not have Lync installed.

**Edit**: Not having Lync installed changes things a lot. If Lync is installed, then Lync will handle setting up the audio call, and will handle the transfer of Audio between the participants in the conversation. Without Lync, you'd have to do that yourself, which won't be straightforward.

Your best bet might be to have your users use the [Lync Web App](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/welcome-to-microsoft-lync-web-app-HA101908015.aspx). This is a web based client that allows external users to join conferences. You'd need to build a [UCMA 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4493baab-6214-4770-8cf9-69c813e8a9fa) application which would sit inside your Lync infrastructure. The app would:

1. Accept a request from your web app to start a new conference, inviting the desired user - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg437521.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448476.aspx)
2. When the conference is created, get the id and return it to the web user
3. In the web client, use the returned id to build a URL that opens the Lync Web App.

I can't remember the syntax of the url off the top of my head, but to get it, you could create a new conference using the Lync Client, then select Invite By Email (from the icon of two "pawns") - this will generate an email containing a URL - clicking the URL take you to a page that gives you conference join options, including installing the web app (you'd need to try the URL on a machine that doesn't have Lync installed to get the option to install the web app)

**Edit:** My bad - the Lync Web App doesn't support Audio. You could actually use the same concept as above, but with the [Lync Attendee Client](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=68a3ca04-a058-4e47-98ea-9e9af7ebd6e3) instead. However, this forces the user to install some components client side, so may not be acceptable in your scenario.

**Edit**: See also the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641027/microsoft-lync-video-streaming-to-webbrowser/5696473#5696473) for more details, this refers to getting video to the client, but is relevant for audio too

Comment: We have already implemented presence in our application. We actually have a complete product with all the IM features. We just want to add the calling capabilities inside our application. And our chat is implemented in a public facing site. So does that mean that the users cannot make calls without Lync installed in their machine?

Comment: Yep - i've edited the answer to add some more info around that scenario

Answer (score 2):

You could create a hyperlink like so

`<a href=”tel:{blah phone number}″>{blah phone number}</a>`

or

`<a href=”sip:{blah sip blah}″>{blah sip blah}</a>`

Which will launch lync from the browser, however if you want to do it inside the browser it seems that you will have to go in to Silverlight. You can find [Silverlight samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436843.aspx) in [Lync Client Side API sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d98f0bf7-c82c-47f5-9f73-be3edbf30438).

Comment: But I've to track and log calls and manage them from my application. I also want to manage the application access as who can make call to whom etc.

Comment: @NLV I think those are fairly fundemental serverside features. You can do them via policies. It's a very [broad set of features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398447.aspx) that I cannot cover here. You should probably check out [technet's dedicated lync site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg293124.aspx) and do some reading. My advice would be to use the built in features, there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

There is an hour-long intro to integrating Lync recorded at Tech-Ed Europe at the end of last year.  I've not watched it yet, but it looks quite good.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/UNC306

Comment: Thanks for the video. Will check it out.